# Replying to an excel info box from vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert a querytable to an excel table from vba using the code below.

```
Set tableRange = Sheets("Fund Performance").Range(Range("C7"),Range("I7").End(xlDown))
On Error Resume Next:
    Sheets("Fund Performance").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tableRange, , xlYes).Name = Symbol
On Error GoTo 0
```

Without the "On Error Resume Next" I get an error 1004
Table cannot overlap a range that contains a pivot table report, **query results**, protected cells or another table.

If I include it, the error does not show up but the table is not created either.

Any advice for dealing with this or alternative method to create excel table from querytable?

Answer (score 0):

While this does not address the primary point of your question, I would like to point out that the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)s that define your **Sheets("Fund Performance").Range** have no explicit worksheet parent. When left to rely on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) to define the parent worksheet, this can produce a,

> <sub>Runtime error 1004:</sub>
>         <sup>Application-defined or object-defined error.</sup>

Best practise is to explicitly define all parent worksheet references for the construction of a Range object.

```
'verbose method
Set tableRange = Sheets("Fund Performance").Range(Sheets("Fund Performance").Range("C7"), Sheets("Fund Performance").Range("I7").End(xlDown))

'with ... end with block method; improved readability, faster execution
With Worksheets("Fund Performance").
    Set tableRange = .Range(.Range("C7"), .Range("I7").End(xlDown))
End With
```

In the latter [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) method, note the use of `.Range` and not `Range`. The prefix period carries the reference to the parent worksheet noted within the With ... End With block. This means that the parent worksheet reference is only established once and reused. In  the former, verbose method, the parent worksheet reference is established and reestablished three times.